# Retrieve both column header and row header for EACH value in sheet

Tags: arrays, if-statement, google-sheets, indexing, google-query-language

I have a sheet that lists the duty roster for teachers. The row headers contain the date of the teacher's duty, and the column headers contain the time segments (9:00 to 9:30, 9:30 to 10:00, etc).

The teacher's name is in the cell intersecting the date and time segment. A teacher's name will appear in multiple rows, at potentially different time segments.

I would like to write a script that will search for a specific teacher and return a list showing all the dates, and the time segment for that date to which the teacher has assigned duty.

I appreciate any and all help. Thank you.

[image: Sample data]

Comment: can you share a copy of your sheet?

Answer (score 1):

its done like this:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(SORT(IFERROR(SPLIT(FLATTEN(IF(B2:D4="",,
 A2:A4&"×"&B1:D1&"×"&B2:D4)), "×"))))
```

[image]

extend ranges as you need and then to filter it down you can use dropdown and `QUERY()` it

**https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/querylanguage**

Comment: Beautiful! Thank you so much.